# Custom Caching Limits for OS X Server

Tags: macos, server.app

In Server Manager, you can set predefined limits for the caching server. Is it possible to set a custom limit? Maybe through Terminal? How do I do this?

I want to limit caching to 100GB but my options are 25GB or 270GB or 755GB or Unlimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options aren't limited to the numbers printed below the scroll bar. You can drag between the options to select a value closer to your desired value:

[image]

---

You can set custom values if you really want to though. The cache size is stored in the **CacheLimit** key in the configuration plist which is located by default here:

```
/Library/Server/Caching/Config/Config.plist
```

```
<key>CacheLimit</key>
<real>268586281855</real>
```

<sup>The integer is bytes.</sup>

Comment: I understand I can select values inbetween, however, I wanted to specifically state 250GB instead of 270 or 145GB. If I can enter my value manually that's all I needed to know how/where.